# requests.get returns 403 in Python Lambda Functions AWS for most of the Urls'

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Trying to check if url's are valid in Python in AWS Lambda functions but most of the url's results return 403.

Works correctly in local.

```
import json
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

def get_domain(link):
    try:
        if not link.startswith("http"):
            link = "http://" + link

        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}

        res = requests.get(link, headers=headers)

        if res.status_code == 200:
            return f"Correct: {link}"
        else:
            return f"Wrong: {link}"
    except:
        return f"Wrong: {link}"


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    print("\n-----Wrong Links-----")
    print(get_domain('wrong'))
    print(get_domain('http://abcd-xyx-wrong.com'))

    print("\n-----Correct Links-----")
    print(get_domain('https://website.com'))
    print(get_domain('google.com'))
    print(get_domain('website.com'))
    print(get_domain('http://website.com'))
    print(get_domain('https://www.website.com'))


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

**Below is the output**

Ideally all links in Correct Links specified are correct but results in 403

```
-----Wrong Links-----
Wrong: http://wrong
Wrong: http://abcd-xyx-wrong.com

-----Correct Links-----
Wrong: https://website.com
Correct: http://google.com
Wrong: http://website.com
Wrong: http://website.com
Wrong: https://www.website.com
Wrong: https://www.bdo.ca
```

Comment: 403 doesn't mean invalid url, it means your request was wrong (4xx), specifically that you are not allowed in there. Bad url would result in requests error (which you catch with `except`), not non-200 code.

Comment: @h4z3 makes sense..  actually 403 links are valid.. my bad